# Can we replace "out" in System.out.println()?

Tags: java

First of all I regret as I am asking a very basic and peculiar question;But I am new to Java as well as programming. I studied that "out" in system.out.println() is an object of system class.Can "out" be Replaced with any other objects of the system class ? If so what are the members and how???

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call [`println()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println--) on any [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html). If you look at the `System` javadoc, you will find [another `PrintStream` static field](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#field.summary), namely `System.err`. For example:

```
System.err.println("This goes to POSIX standard error!");
```

If you want to actually replace standard out with your own output stream, you can pass your stream to [`System.setOut(PrintStream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut-java.io.PrintStream-) or the corresponding `System.setErr(PrintStream)`

Answer (score 1):

here are 2 very useful links (hope this helps)

1. [Javapapers: system.out.print](http://javapapers.com/core-java/system-out-println/)
2. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

here's a short description of it below :

```
Structure of System.out.println
```

Following is the skeletal structure of System.out.println in the JDK source. Through this code snippet the essential parts are highlighted and its given for better understanding.

```
public final class System {
 static PrintStream out;
 static PrintStream err;
 static InputStream in;
 ...
}
 public class PrintStream extends FilterOutputStream {
 //out object is inherited from FilterOutputStream class
  public void println() {
...
 }
```

Change out of System.out.println

`‘out’` object can be customized. out gets initialized by java runtime environment at startup and it can be changed by developer during execution. 
Instead of standard output, in default cases when you run a program through command line, the output is printing in the same command window. We can change that behavior using setOut method as below.

In the following example

```
public class ChangeOut {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("log.txt")));
        System.out.println("Now the output is redirected!");
    } catch(Exception e) {}
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes

`System.setOut(out)` does just that.

where `out` can be any instance of `PrintStream`.

For example :

`System.setOut(System.err);` would set the default output stream to be the same as the default error stream.

Comment: "Can "out" be Replaced with any other objects of the system class ?", not "can I replace out with my own object?"

Answer (score 0):

yes. you can use different key words as System.err.println() or system.in and different , you can get the complete view here http://javapapers.com/core-java/system-out-println/ in this link you can have a complete tutorial thing for you.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, e.g. err

But I would download any of Java IDE (Intellij IDEA or Ecliplse), create a new java project, new class, new main method, type System.out and hit Ctrl + Space and see what happens

Comment: Why would you specifically state to use an IDE (where documentation is sometimes finicky to bring up and keyboard mappings differ)? Would a standard javadoc not suffice?

Comment: You can play with IDE. He is a newbie.