# RMI - How client can get server console output?

Tags: java, rmi

I need that all server console output will appear in client output.

I'm invoking remote method on remote VM, during remote method execution i have some log4j report to the console (on remote).

I want to get/ return all log4j report to my client side console.

is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. You have to understand that client and server **only** communicate through that RMI interface that you defined. Then both programs run in their **own** JVM; so stdout is something completely different for client and server. Same is of course true for any kind of logging infrastructure.

If you really want to push the server messages into your client logs; then you need to *enhance* that RMI interface, for example by allow the server to send back a `List<String>` that contains all the messages.

But please note: that is a rather bad design idea. You **really** do not want that your client logs contain **server** details. What happens on the server ... stays on the server. Your clients have **no** business knowing about such details. Because your **users** might find it very helpful when planning to attack your server ... to know what that thing is doing in detail!

Update: given your input, I would go for the following::

1. Make sure that you can really capture any char printed to stdout/stderr on your server; for example by "replacing" stdout/stderr so that anything printed there goes in some file (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27103706/can-we-replace-out-in-system-out-println)). Alternatively, if your VM is Linux, you can make sure both get piped into files.
2. Instead of trying to capture stuff within your RMI service, I would go for a simpler solution - by adding a RMI interface that allows you to **pull** those stdout/stderr files from your server. In other words: keep your current RMI calls as they are; but built another service that you can use to retrieve full log files at arbitrary points in time.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!! the reason that i want to get the remote console output is because that i perform automation test , the flow is that i perform some deploy to remote VM , then i want to run some automation test on the remote that check my deployment and return console output that include my automation verification

Comment: this is actually what i thought..  i refactor my RMI interface by including return list of string that read my log4j file output after remote method invocation, so i hope that is good solution. thanks for your advice!

Comment: i'll ! i have another issue how i should run my server via cmd? the issue that when i run via cmd the main terminate and not wait for client.. with the  eclipse when i run it wait and not terminate

Comment: But that is a **completely** different thing. You asked a specific question; and you got an answer. Asking *more* questions in comments is **not** how this site operates. I would suggest that A) first do quite some research B) get your requirements straight C) write up a **new** question for your *new* question, ideally containing an [mcve]. That said: if your code *waits* for something to happen on the other hand, then it will wait. So you will have to look into writing your code a different way.