# Include logs of external library using printStackTrace

Tags: java, logback, slf4j, stderr

There is an external library that is using `e.printStackTrace();` in the catch blocks.

The web application itself uses slf4j with logback writing the logs to a file (rolling file appender).

Is there any way to include those stack traces into the file based logs too (preferably first without modifying the library)?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the `System.err` stream. This will then redirect any output on the error-stream. Be aware, that there is both an `out` and an `err`.

[Can we replace "out" in System.out.println()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27103706/can-we-replace-out-in-system-out-println) says:

> `System.setErr(PrintStream)`

By replacing the `err` stream, you can capture and redirect the e.printStackTrace, because that prints to `System.err`.